# Autodoc failing with class that has nested pydantic model

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydantic, autodoc, autodoc-pydantic

As my MRE, I've got the following file:

blah.py

```py
'''Blah module'''

import pydantic

class Foo:
    '''Foo class'''

    class Bar(pydantic.BaseModel):
        '''Bar class'''

        x: str = pydantic.Field(description='The x.')

        @pydantic.validator('x')
        def do_nothing(cls, value: str) -> str:
            return value
```

I'm attempting to use Sphinx to generate documentation for this module.  In my conf.py, I have

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinxcontrib.autodoc_pydantic',
]
```

My blah.rst is

```
Blah
====

.. automodule:: blah.blah
    :members:
```

I've pip installed `pydantic` and `autodoc_pydantic`.

However, when I `make html`, I get

```py
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/user/Projects/Workspace/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/autodoc_pydantic/inspection.py", line 311, in __init__
    self.attribute: Dict = self.model.Config
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'Config'
```

It appears that `autodoc_pydantic` thinks that `Foo` inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel` when it's really `Bar` that does.  If I remove `'sphinxcontrib.autodoc_pydantic'` from `extensions`, the error goes away.

More interestingly, if I delete the validator, the error goes away as well.

`autodoc_pydantic` is version 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in version 1.7.2.